# MQTT on Parse platform (Open source parse Server)

Tags: mqtt, parse-server, back4app

Hi I am using the hosted version of the open source parse platform (hosed version on Back4app) for my IoT project. Am using HTTP (REST) Api to communicate with the parse server and upload data. Does anyone know if it is possible to use the MQTT protocol instead of HTTP for the same with the parseplatform. I couldn't find any relevant doc for this. Apparently there's a way to install the MQTTjs on cloud code section of the platform but do not know if this really works ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, I just tested it now and it worked for me. Here are the steps that you need to follow:

1 - You only need to install this npm module as you can see at [this guide](https://help.back4app.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002038772-How-to-install-a-NPM-module-at-Back4App-).

Here is my package.json:

```
{
      "dependencies": {
           "mqtt": "2.18.8"
      }
}
```

2 - After that, on Back4app, you need to upload the code in your cloud code and check your Server System Logs at Server Settings > Logs > Settings.

Here's a simple code that you can use to test it. I put this code in my main.js:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
});
```

Comment: Hi Ramos great to see your reply ... Donyou know whether same is possible on the open source version parseplatform.org as well ... I would imagine so but can't be sure ... A big thanks

Comment: Hi Sijones, probably it's possible on open source too, but I didn't test it.